# Pass commands to jsconsole from Shell

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox, cmd

i would like to know if there is a way to pass commands to firefox javascript console DIRECTLY from the cmd e.g something like

```
start firefox.exe -jsconsole "screenshot --fullpage out.jpg"
```

thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @slebetman well i was looking into apps that take screenshot of a webpage .. i found many apps e.g CutyCapt .. and then found out that it's possible to take screenshot via firefox developer console by typing `screenshot --fullpage out.jpg` so i thought maybe if there's a way to access the jsconsole via cmd i won't need any additional apps for the job . just trying to learn here